# How to pass parameter to Ext.data.Store?

Tags: extjs

I am using following code:

```
var genres1 = new Ext.data.Store({
    reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
        fields: ['pincode','place_name'],
        root: 'rows'
    }),
   proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        url: 'pointalong.php',
        method: 'GET'
   })
});
```

but i want to pass 3 parameters to my php file. how should i proccess? and also how would i get at php file.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are two possibilities. The first one is to use store `baseParams` config:

```js
var genres1 = new Ext.data.Store({
    baseParams: {
        param1: 'value1',
        param2: 'value2'
    },
    // ...
```

The second one is to send them when you are using [load](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-load) method:

```js
genres1.load({params: {param2: 'anotherValue'}});
```

> **Note**: *params* will override any *baseParams* of the same name

So if you setup store with `baseParams` like in example above and then use `load` with params the store will request `...?param1=value1&param2=anotherValue`.

---

> ... and also how would i get at php file

As usual variable passed via the URL parameters - using [$_GET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php):

```php
$param1 = $_GET['param1'];
```

Comment: @Sudhir If you are using ExtJs 4 you will want to use the "extraParams" config option and you will use it on the proxy, not the store itself.  What version of ExtJs are you working with?

Answer (score 16):

I use this and it works perfectly

```
Ext.define('store.odon.DiagnosticoStore', {
extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
model : 'model.odont.DiagnosticoModel',
    proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    api: {
        create: CONTEXT_PATH + '/mvc/odona/crear', 
        read: CONTEXT_PATH + '/mvc/odon/lista',
        update: CONTEXT_PATH + '/mvc/odon/update',
        destroy: CONTEXT_PATH + '/mvc/odon/delete'
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'diagnosticos',
        successProperty: 'success'
    },
    writer: {
        type: 'json',
        writeAllFields: true,
        encode: true,
        root: 'diagnosticos'
    }
}
});
```

the parameter is assigned to load the store

```
 var storeDiagnostico= getStore(); // Ext.create('store.odon.DiagnosticoStore');
        storeDiagnostico.getProxy().setExtraParam("idOdontologia", value);
        storeDiagnostico.load();
```

Comment: plus in the php
$idOdontologia=$_GET['idOdontologia'];

Answer (score 5):

If the value of the parameter may change (for example, if it comes from another form field), then the most reliable way is to apply the proxy parameter before the load event each time the store loads, as follows:

```
 Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    ...
    listeners:{
        beforeload: function(store){
            var filterText = Ext.getCmp('filterText').value;
            store.getProxy().setExtraParam("filterText", filterText);
        }
    },
```